# Sorting two arrays of different data types in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have the following problem:
I have two arrays of a different data type, e.g.

```
byte[] a = {2,5,3};
long[] b = {2,0,1};
```

And I want b to get sorted and the entries in a must be changed respectively, s.t. I get

```
byte[] a = {5,3,2};
long[] b = {0,1,2};
```

I've seen that most people do that with a Comparator but that doesn't seem to work with different data types. I am looking for an efficient solution as the array lengths will be very large. However, a has only two different entries 0 and 1 (but I still want to keep it as byte to have the option for more entries) and all pairs (0,x) are already sorted (that means if I only pick pairs where the first entry is a 0 then it is already sorted). The same holds also for pairs (1,x'), but the entries in b are not completely sorted. I hope my problem got clear. I am happy for any suggestions.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: Apparently this question: [Sort a parallel array using Arrays.sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835047/sort-a-parallel-array-using-arrays-sort?noredirect=1&lq=1) is very similar. However I wasn't able to reproduce any working example. Does anyone have a full working example?

Comment: Rather than have these "parallel" collections, it would almost certainly be cleaner to create a new class with a `byte` and a `long`, then a *single* collection/array of that type. Then you can just sort that collection/array using a comparator for that type.

Comment: I've solved it now by going to one data type and using something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232788/procedure-to-sort-a-two-dimensional-int-array-depending-on-column However, I'm not happy with that solution, but it is okay for the moment...

Answer (score 0):

I would try to solve your problem if you tagged your question [c](/questions/tagged/c), but in [java](/questions/tagged/java) your problem description shows, that you're missing a class.

```
public class MyClass implements Comparable {

    private byte;
    private long;
    //getters setters
    //compare method according to your requirements.
}
```

Then you'll have `MyClass[]` which you will be able to sort.

And in case you want to stick to your problem, simply implement a sort algorithm, sort one of your arrays and when only you perform a swap, swap elements in the second array too.